# Путаница с разрядностью MinGW-w64

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64

Никак не могу разобраться со следующим вопросом.

Я хочу использовать компилятор **MinGW-w64**, так как он предоставляет более полную поддержку **WinAPI**, по сравнению с компилятором **MinGW32**.

Хочу иметь возможность собирать и для **x32**, и для **x64** платформ. Судя по информации, которую мне удалось найти, для этого необходимо ставить две версии **MinGW-w64**.

Я нашел лишь официальный установщик компилятора:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/.

Если опустить варианты настройки потоков и исключений, а рассмотреть только целевую архитектуру, то установщик позволяет установить две версии компилятора:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0
```

Методом *тыка* мне удалось определить, что **i686** собирает только для **х32**, а **х86_64** - только для **х64**.

Эти обозначения меня окончательно запутывают, ведь обычно через **х86** обозначается **х32**...

Мои вопросы:

1. При использовании **MinGW-w64** для сборки **x32** и **x64** кода обязательно ставить две версии компилятора?
2. Если я правильно понимаю значение термина *кросс-компиляция*, то получается, что **MinGW-w64** не предназначен для перекрестной компиляции, поскольку собирает код только той же разрядности, которой обладает сам? При использовании этого компилятора невозможно собрать **x64** код из-под **x32** системы, потому что **x64** версия компилятора не может быть запущена на **х32** системе (в общем случае). Однако, можно собирать **x32** код в **x64** системе путем запуска **x32** версии компилятора благодаря средствам совместимости **Windows WoW**, но этот способ не относится к перекрестной компиляции. Все так?

Comment: И разрядность компилятора и разрядность целевой платформы одновременно.

Comment: С чем это связано? Я думал, что разрядность компилятора не зависит от разрядности целевого выпуска. То есть, я полагал, что двоичные файлы компилятора могут быть как **х32**, так и **х64**. А так получается, что для сборки **х32** кода компилятор должен обладать такой же разрядностью?

Comment: Теоретически не зависит. Но на практике, во-первых, кросс-компиляторы сложнее и объёмнее, так как им надо как минимум иметь копии статических библиотек обеих разрядностей, а во-вторых, часто разрядность машины разработчика совпадает с разрядностью целевой машины.

Comment: `ведь обычно через х86 обозначается х32` — нет, через x86 обозначают все Intel 8086-совместимые архитектуры. x86-32 — 32-разрядные, x86-64 — 64-разрядные.

Comment: i686, в свою очередь, означает линейку P6 (Intel Celeron и Pentium), то есть гарантированную поддержку команд тех процессоров. Линейка та, к слову, была сугубо 32-битной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да, надо ставить 2 версии:

   - `i686-posix-dwarf` - для сборки 32-х битных программ;
   - `x86_64-posix-seh` - для сборки 64-х битных программ.

И да, компилятор для сборки 64-х битных программ, сам по себе 64-х битный, так что из 32-х битной Windows собрать 64-х битный бинарник не получится.

2. Под кросс-компиляцией ещё можно понимать сборку из-под Linux/macOS бинарников для Windows. И Mingw-w64 такое умеет. Но опять же, для 32-х и 64-х битных целей сборки надо ставить отдельные наборы:

   - с префиксом `i686-w64-mingw32-` для 32-х бит;
   - с префиксом `x86_64-w64-mingw32-` для 64-х бит.